# Python Implementing a module that is shared by all other modules

Tags: python, singleton, project

I'm making a Notepad program for linux with python. I want to implement a main module so that other modules can fetch and set data to that module.

I've tried implementing singleton class in the main module. 
But whenever I import it in other modules, it keeps getting initialized, ruining the data inside the class.

**MainModule.py**

```
class Database(object):
    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__instance == None:
            cls.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
            cls.__instance.name = "Database"
        return cls.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.__title = "initial"
```

**SubModule.py**

```
    from MainModule import Database

    class example(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.database = Database()
```

I changed the `self.__title` to `"untitled"`, then after importing this module to other modules, I just get an initial value.

How do I make it so that it initialize only once even after getting instantiated in other modules?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you need to set class attributes that can be shared amongst the instancies, and "initialize" those value only the first time an instance is created, right?

Comment: Another question: what's the relation with pyqt? This seems to be a general oriented python question, or is there some strictly PyQt related data/object you need to access to? If that's the case, can you edit your question and clarify it?

Comment: You don't need a singleton class. Just use an normal class and create a module-level instance of it in `MainModule`. Then you can do `from MainModule import database` and you will get the same instance every time. (PS: your current code doesn't work because `__init__` is called every time you execute `Database()`).

Comment: @musicamante Oops sorry, fixed it. And also yes I was trying to initialize once only when it is created.

Comment: @ekhumoro Hey I think it works! Thanks!